# material-ui withStyle not working with resux-form

Tags: redux, material-ui, redux-form

I'm currently working on my first real React-Redux app (ReactDom to be exact).
The app is using material ui (I'm not the project manager)

I'm having trouble applying style to a component exported via reduxForm.
my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { some acttions } from '../actions';


const styles = (theme) => ({});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    some: () => dispatch(some(data)),
    actions: () => dispatch(actions())
})


class FormComponent extends Component {
// Component with form
}

FormComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(FormComponent));

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm'
})(FormComponent);
```

This results in `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` pointing to the command with connect. When I erase withStyle, it doesn't break, but looks bad.

Thanks in Advance,
Gal

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Worked. Perfectly.
Also When I re(Copy-Paste)ed it back to my IDE. Worked perfectly.
Bug Life....